# Can InstallShield add application to Windows Firewall exception list?

Tags: .net, wcf, installshield, firewall

I have developed a Windows Service running WCF service. I use InstallShield to make a setup. But Windows Firewall blocks the service after installation. How can I make the setup program to add the service to firewall exception list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InstallShield doesn't have native firewall configuration support.  One possibility is to use an EXE custom action to call netsh.  The approach that I like is to use Windows Installer XMl in conjunction with InstallShield.

I create a merge module in WiX and reference the firewall extension. Build the merge module and then add it as a dependency to my InstallShield project.   The final MSI will then be mostly InstallShield with a little bit of WiX table data mixed in to do the magic.    The advantage here is that the WiX custom actions are very well coded and thoroughly tested.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe then it's better to use WiX instead of InstallShield to create the installation package?

Comment: Possibly, it depends on what the installation requirements are and how much code you already have written.  Each tool has it's strengths and weaknesses.  If you are mostly happy with where you are and just need some firewall tweaks, then the above answer may be enough.  If you aren't really happy then an analysis may or may not indicate that a switch to WiX would be better.

Comment: I switched to Wix. Works fine. Thank you again